# Append items from array to html element - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How to append array items to html elemnt like this :

```
[1,2,3]

<div class="bi bj">
   <div class="bi bj">
      <strong>Suggestions</strong>
      <div><label class="bo bp"><input type="checkbox" name="addees[0]" value="0">Default</label></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

so it will be like this :

```
 <div class="bi bj">
   <div class="bi bj">
      <strong>Suggestions</strong>
      <div><label class="bo bp"><input type="checkbox" name="addees[0]" value="0">Default</label></div>
      <div><label class="bo bp"><input type="checkbox" name="addees[1]" value="1">Test 1</label></div>
      <div><label class="bo bp"><input type="checkbox" name="addees[2]" value="2">Test 2</label></div>
      <div><label class="bo bp"><input type="checkbox" name="addees[3]" value="3">Test 3</label></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

so far I know how to select div by class name

```
document.getElementsByClassName("bi bj")[2];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see any attempt of appending anything.... Please share your attempt(s) and explain where/which part you seem to be having problems with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of great HTML template solutions.  Personally, I like http://handlebarsjs.com/ but there are lots to choose from.  I recommend you take a look.

That said, you can also do this mostly yourself like:

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3];
var target = document.querySelector(".bi.bj .bi.bj");
var template = "<div><label class=\"bo bp\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"addees[~id~]\" value=\"~id~\">Test ~id~</label></div>";

items.forEach(function(item) {
  target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", template.replace(/~id~/g, item));
});
```

```html
<div class="bi bj">
  <div class="bi bj">
    <strong>Suggestions</strong>
    <div><label class="bo bp"><input type="checkbox" name="addees[0]" value="0">Default</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= adees.length(); i++) {
    x = document.createElement('div').innerHTML = "<label class='bo bp'><input type='checkbox' name='adees[" + adees[i] + "]' value=" + adees[i] + ">Test " + adees[i] + "</label></div>";
    document.body.appendChild(x);
};
```

Comment: 1st: `adees.length`, without braces, 2nd: `(x = document.createElement('div')).innerHTML` otherwise `x` contains the string, not the div, and 3rd. i doubt that `document.body` is the right place to append these nodes

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommed you to read some js and jquery tutorials.

The answer(it uses jquery)

```
<div class="bi bj" id="uniqueId">
      <strong>Suggestions</strong>
      <div><label class="bo bp"><input type="checkbox" name="addees[0]" value="0">Default</label></div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()) {
var array = [1,2,3];
array.forEach(function(elem){
    $('#uniqueId').append('<div><label class="bo bp"><input type="checkbox" name="addees[' + elem + ']" value="' + elem + '">Test' + elem + '</label></div>')
}, this);
}
</script>
```

Comment: imo. it's better to first create a template: `function rowTemplate(elem){ return '<div><label class="bo bp"><input type="checkbox" name="addees[' + elem + ']" value="' + elem + '">Test' + elem + '</label></div>' }` Then apply this template to the data, and append the whole/concatenated result to the DOM: `$('#uniqueId').append( array.map( rowTemplate ).join('\n') )`, instead of parsing markup and appending nodes for each item in the Array.

Comment: @Thomas In that time I have missed your comment) Thank you for feedback, I think it make sense in some cases